# Java subclass doesn't have enough arguments

Tags: java

I am learning Java OOP reading a book, and it doesn't explain very well the sub classes topic. I am trying to make a class that solves a system of equations, you can find the code [here](http://pastebin.com/qsRVHV19).

The class `sistemi` solves systems of 2 equations and the subclass `sistemi3eq` solves systems with 3 equations. NetBeans is giving me this error:

[image]

I haven't found a lot of documentation. Do you have any suggestion? How could I improve my code?

Comment: No need for the `()`.

Comment: Also, note that types in Java (i.e. class names) should start with capital letter, i.e. `Sistemi`.

Comment: Anyway i think you should rethink your design..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class name don't (and can't) have `()` so why you do `extends sistemi()`?

Just `extends sistemi`

Comment: Indeed.  But therefore the question should be close-voted as "simple typographical error" ;)

Comment: The error is the same that you can see on the question.

Comment: I have removed the braces. Now it is 'class sistemi3eq extends sistemi '

Comment: `sistemi` is a class?

Comment: yes, sistemi is a class. There is also the file called sistemi.java --> http://i.imgur.com/pjoUPpd.png

Comment: Ok, i see now the link to the code... the problem is "sistemi" don't have a constructor without args, so in sistemi3eq constructor you should add the call to super(double a, double b, double c, double d, double e, double f)

Comment: @AlbertoRossi: In that case, please construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and post the code in your question (not an image please).

Comment: Another error: if sistemi3eq is a constructor, it can't return void

Comment: Thank you, I have removed the void and I don't have anymore that error. But where should I call the 'super()' ?

Comment: Inside sistemi3eq constructor, or you could add a no-args constructor to class `sistemi` if you don't need it. -- Please read this for more info, you will understand this `super`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Answer (score 1):

Your subclass is not actually within your parent class. You need to move it within the scope of your parent class. You can't have two separate pubilc classes in one file.

Since the second isn't public, you can still use it that way, but you really shouldn't. You should put it within the `sistemi` class or in another file.

```
public class sistemi {
    ...

//this bracket here needs to go at the bottom of the file
//}

    class sistemi3eq extends sistemi {

        ...
    }    
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have assigned void at `sistemi(double a, double b, double c, double d, double e, double f)` and now it works.

```
public class sistemi {

    private Double x;
    private Double y;

    public void sistemi(double a, double b, double c, double d, double e, double f) {
     //calcolo nella matrice
     double detx = (c*e)-(b*f);
     double dety = (a*f)-(c*d);
     double det = (a*e)-(d*b);

     //calcolo dei risultati x e y del sistema
     if (det != 0) {
      x = detx/det;
      y = dety/det;
     } 
    }

    //funzioni varie
    other code
}

class sistemi3eq extends sistemi {

    private Double x;
    private Double y;
    private Double z;

    //other code    
}
```

Comment: now it's not anymore a constructor anyway (i never thought you can create a method with same name of the class). Maybe you want it to be static